# (C++) Is there any reason to not work with an open file?

Tags: c++, file-io, c++17, standards

While writing a small bit of text-processing code, I realized that with the notation I was using, it would be possible to simply do all of my processing upon import, which would cut down on an entire cycle within the loop. However, it would mean that my code would do a lot of processing while the file is open, using data from said file, and my gut instinct says that proper programmers might have something to say about that (though just as easily you might not, since I am only a student still).

Basically, I want to turn this (note that the code is unfinished)...

```
int minPalindromeSteps(std::string input) {
    //Step 1: Import a list of palindromes from a file
    //Note: the file is assumed to be encoded in standard ASCII and all lowercase, this code is not generalized for unicode
    set<string> Palindromes {};
        {//Open a new scope so that temp variables end sooner
        string word {};
        std::ifstream word_file;
        word_file.open("palindromes.txt");
        if (!word_file.is_open())throw std::runtime_error("Error: File opening failed.");
        while (word_file >> word){//Recall: >> operator delineates using whitespace
            if ( input == word ) return 0;//if the word is already a palindrome
            else Palindromes.insert(word);
        }
        word_file.close();
        }//End dummy scope

    //Step 2: Determine which words (if any) are the "potential palindrome"
    set<string> shortlist {};
    for (auto& word: Palindromes){//note: everthing inside this loop could be moved to the while above, but my gut tells 
                                 //me not to do operations directly to an open file
        bool shortlisted = true;//reset the shorlist flag to true
        for (unisgned i {0}; i < input.length(); i++){
            if ( input.at(i) != word.at(i) ){
                shortlisted = false;
                break;
            }//end if
        }//end for 2
        if (shortlisted) shortlist.insert(word);
    }// end for 1
}
```

into this:

```
int minPalindromeSteps(std::string input) {
    //Step 1: Import a list of palindromes from a file
    //Note: the file is assumed to be encoded in standard ASCII and all lowercase, this code is not generalized for unicode
    set<string> shortlist {};//THIS WAS RENAMED
        {//Open a new scope so that temp variables end sooner
        string word {};
        std::ifstream word_file;
        word_file.open("palindromes.txt");
        if (!word_file.is_open())throw std::runtime_error("Error: File opening failed.");
        while (word_file >> word){//Recall: >> operator delineates using whitespace
            if ( input == word ) return 0;//if the word is already a palindrome
            else {//EVERYTHING WAS MOVED INTO THIS ELSE
                bool shortlisted = true;//reset the shorlist flag to true
                for (unisgned i {0}; i < input.length(); i++){
                    if ( input.at(i) != word.at(i) ){
                        shortlisted = false;
                        break;
                    }//end if
                }//end for
                if (shortlisted) shortlist.insert(word);
            }
        }
        word_file.close();
        }//End dummy scope

    //Step 2: Determine which words (if any) are the "potential palindrome"

    for (auto& word: Palindromes){
        /* EVERYTHING WAS MOVED ABOVE */
    }// end for 1
}
```

...and I'm wondering if there's some coding principle, unspoken rule, or the like not to work with open files for too long, or if it simply down to personal preference and code readability.

Comment: "Proper programmers" will say it depends.   Do you expect to have more than one program/process attempting to open the file at the same time?   If one process has the file open, and another attempts to open it, how does that affect the other process (e.g. will it wait for access and does that waiting affect the user, will it continue with good or bad data, etc)?   Is the file large in comparison with available memory?   Once "processing" is done, does the program need anything other than "processed" data from the file?  The list of considerations keeps growing.

Comment: That basically answers my question then. Basically, what I was wondering was whether or not there was a definitive "no, don't" or whether it was an "it depends." IE, I wanted to know if it was generally considered bad practice to leave the file open and work with its data, rather than import all the data into, say, a set, and _then_ work on the data.

It appears that within the scope of what I am doing, it is fine to process the data as it is imported, but for code in a larger structure it is generally better to work with a "copy." 

Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: It also depends on the count of palindromes you expect to have in your file.  You don't handle 10 items the same ways you'd handle a million.

Comment: For usual *ix commands like e.g. `cat`, I would expect that the input and output file is open for roughly the whole process life-time. Such commands become more powerful when they depend on internal buffering (which could be exhausted) as less as possible. For a GUI application, I would try to close the files as soon as possible. (I often get complaints from testers and users: "Can't you make the loading/saving faster?") ;-)